# What should I use to create a login system for multiple sites similar to SO?

Tags: .net, authentication, openid, oauth, single-sign-on

I am in the process of creating a series of websites and web applications that will be hosted on a dedicated server that I own and host. They will be developed on Windows Server 2008, IIS7 and .NET 4, SQL Server 2008 and Entity Framework. This will be a live server as well as a place for me to learn how to do some new stuff.

- A user will have a single Username/Password for all sites
- A user can have different levels of access on each site
- The login needs to be persistent across sessions "Remember Me"
- "Logout" logs the user out from all sites
- There will be some parts of the sites where Anonymous is allowed

I have looked at OpenId and OAuth and I am not sure that either one of these really fits the bill. I do not want to use something like Twitter to handle authentication as I have heard that it is full of holes.

Comment: Which technology will the sites be developed in?

Comment: OAuth really isn't a login system.  OAuth is about authorization (what can you do?) and not about authentication (who are you?).  Of course, you have to know who it is (authenticate) to know what they can do (authorized?), so part of OAuth *is* to authenticate - but not in the traditional "login and create a session" type of manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is a post giving an outline of how they did it.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/)

[And here is even more detail.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work/64274#64274)